# drupal i18n - show 404 when translation does not exist

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, internationalization, http-status-code-404

On a drupal 7 using i18n, when a translation for a language does not exist,

I want it to show the 404 - not found page instead of a blank page.

Is that possible?